# What do I find material to understand which electronic components are needed for a microcontroller?

Tags: pcb-design, keyboard

I'm interested in designing a PCB for a keyboard, and I can't seem to find materials on learning what components are needed for the board (resistors, capacitors, diodes etc). I understand basic electronics, but in terms of a microcontroller which require what resistor, how many is needed, I can't find it. Googling "PCB designs" only give me details about best practices etc what I need to learn but not the electronic design of it. Can someone direct me to sources or give me an answer on how do I figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered the datasheet for the microcontroller?

Comment: Maybe your best bet is to find a reference design and copy it.

Comment: From what you describe, you might consider working with a good development board before trying to design a pcb,

Comment: Why do you think you need some? Microcontrollers are generally meant to be self-contained. You probably only need power-supply decoupling, and the rest is up to your specific circuit.

Comment: Ask not what you can do for your microcontroller, but what your microcontroller can do for you... and what it *can't* do for you, because that is the part you'll have to design.

Comment: The information you seek is contained in a 2yr (minimum) or 4-yr electronics engineering degree.  To *know* why those resistors and capacitors are used the way they are, requires fundamental understanding of many aspects of circuit design (analog, digital, even some RF.) Any datasheet or reference design may help you get working quickly, but none will answer these questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters, I think you are approaching this wrong. You don't design a circuit by asking "Where should I put resistors? Where should I put capacitors?"

That's like cooking by asking "Where should I put flour? Where should I put eggs? Where should I put sardines?"

Rather, there is *something you want to do*, and resistors and capacitors are *how* you can do that thing. If you want to make a cake, you look up how to make a cake - and it will tell you what to do with the flour and the eggs, and it will not even mention sardines, because cakes shouldn't have sardines.

---

Depending on the microcontroller, you might need some components just to make it power up. These *should* be described in its datasheet. If it's complicated enough, they'll probably even give you an example schematic to make it simpler. The microcontroller company does want you to be able to use their microcontrollers.

If you don't know about datasheets - now you do. Ever reputable manufacturer releases datasheets for **all** its products, containing all the information they hope you could possibly need. (Sometimes you can't get the datasheet without being a big company and signing an NDA. In that case, don't buy that part.) Even things like resistors have datasheets, although you rarely need to refer to them.

If they give you an example schematic (or "reference design") and the design works for you, it's generally fine to just copy it. Even professional designers do copy these designs when suitable. If it's *not* suitable for your needs, like if it has the wrong power supply voltage, you can change it - it's an example, not a law. But you will have to understand what you're changing.

Note that datasheets are often written for people who know what they're looking for, so you may find it hard to find the relevant information. If we knew which microcontroller you wanted to use we could help you find it.

---

The rest of the circuit is *entirely up to you*. Let's say the microcontroller wants 3.3 volts and you want to power your keyboard from 5 volts USB. How can you get 3.3 volts? It's entirely up to you! The microcontroller datasheet won't help you with that. The microcontroller company has nothing to do with your power supply.

Lots of people have done it before, though, because lots of chips want 3.3 volts and lots of people want to power them from USB. You should be able to find some suggestions by Googling it or asking here.

And you want it to read keyboard buttons, presumably. The microcontroller will have "digital inputs" - wire connections where your program can detect whether there is a voltage on the wire or not. You have to design the circuit that puts voltage on the input when the key is pressed, and not when it's not pressed.

And you might want NumLock and CapsLock LEDs (who uses ScrollLock?). The microcontroller will have "digital outputs" - wire connections where your program can tell it to either output a voltage or not. You have to design the circuit that makes the LEDs light up when the microcontroller outputs a voltage, and not when it doesn't.

And wait, you have 100 keyboard buttons but you only have 20 connections to the microcontroller. Can you make that work without buying a really big microcontroller? Have people done that before? (spoiler: they have)

The point is, this stuff doesn't actually have anything to do with the microcontroller - it's a completely separate part of the circuit. You, as the circuit designer, have to take all these different bits of circuit, that you get from different places, and combine them into one big circuit that makes a keyboard. There's no one information source that will tell you everything you want to do. There are pieces you have to put together yourself.

---

If you're stuck, you can always ask here, but remember that Stack Exchange is intended for specific questions and you have to try to solve your own problem first.

- "How do I make a keyboard?" is too broad.
- "How do I convert 5V power to 3.3V power?" is okay (and someone's probably asked it before so you should search first).
- "How can I detect whether a button is pressed, from a microcontroller?" is okay (and someone's probably asked it before so you should search first).
- "Why won't my microcontroller turn on?" is okay. When asking why something didn't work for *you*, make sure to provide as much relevant information as you can, and always include a schematic.
- "What is the best microcontroller?" is not allowed because it's a "shopping question". Answers to "shopping questions" easily become obsolete over time.
- "How many digital outputs does this microcontroller have?" is technically *allowed*, but if it's written in the datasheet, it'll get downvoted and not answered because you should've looked in the datasheet. Spoiler: it's in the datasheet.
- "I don't understand this part of the datasheet. What does it mean?" is absolutely okay.
- "This information should be in the datasheet but it *isn't*, where can I find it?" is also okay.

There is a [help section](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) with information about [what things you can ask about](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (electronics design is one of them, including keyboards) and [what kinds of questions are not allowed](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) (such as shopping questions).

Comment: `cakes shouldn't have sardines` ... they should, if it's a birthday cake for a dog or a cat ... lol

Comment: They could if they were fishcakes :)

Comment: @user253751 Thank you! thats a very comprehensive answer! i understand better what to ask now. i think that was the issue, with so many things to consider, where do i start first. i think ill look at which microcontroller i want to use first to suit my needs, initially i was going for the atmega32u4 which is apparently widely used in custom kb pcb designs but i think ill take your advise on suiting it to my needs and doing a bit of research!

Comment: @NicholasGoo Feel free to just use the atmega32u4. If it works for everyone else, it will probably work for you too. Do check, though. Or, you can learn about the world of microcontrollers. I believe the whole atmega series (in fact the whole AT series) is quite old now - new parts have lots more memory and run much faster. On the other hand, because the atmega series is old it's basically battle-hardened - everyone knows how to use it.